# Помогите найти ошибку в функции перевода

Tags: c++, строки, системы-счисления, теория-чисел

Нужно осуществить перевод из 7ой системы счисления в десятичную.
Вводил число я в виде строки, после чего переводил в число.
Но на моменте перевода в 10ую систему мне выдает по итогу мусор вместо 69
В чем ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int size(string str)
{
int i = 0;
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    i++;
}
return i;
}

int atoi(string str, int a)
{
int x=0;
for (int i = 0; i < size(str); i++)
{
    a=x += (int(str[i]) - int('0')) * pow(10, (size(str) - i) - 1);
}
return a;
}

int translaterIn10(string str, int a, int arr[])
{
int i = 0;
while (a / 10 != 0)
{
    arr[i] = a % 10;
    a /= 10;
    i++;
}
//arr[i]=6, 2, 1;
//6 * 7^0 + 2 * 7^1 + 1 * 7^2=69;
int c=0;
for (int i = 0; i < size(str); i++)
{
    c += arr[i]*pow(7, i);
}

return c;
}

int main()
{
string str1;
int *arr = new int[size(str1)];
int a=0;
cout << "Enter your number in sevenfold number system:\n";
cin >> str1;
cout << "Your number in sevenfold number system:\n" << str1 << endl;
atoi(str1, a);
cout<<"Your number in decimal system:\n"<<translaterIn10(str1, a, arr);
delete[] arr;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: я вижу в функции atoi() return, но не вижу в коде, что он используется.

Comment: 7-ая - всмысле семиричная?

Comment: функция `size` - ваша идея? Вы в курсе что у `std::string` есть соответствующий метод `size`? Зачем пытаться отстрелить себе ногу?

Comment: я в atoi пишу return чтобы потом поместить возвращаемое значение atoi в функцию перевода

Comment: нам запрещают пользоваться стандартными функциями

Comment: @stpd__prg запрещают пользоваться стандартными функциями... Во-первых `std::string::size()` - метод, а не функция, во-вторых вы же ими пользуетесь (`pow`, `new`, ввод-вывод)... И пишите @user_name когда к кому-то обращаетесь, чтобы этот человек получил уведомление

Comment: вернее, все методы/функции со строками нужно писать самому

Comment: @stpd__prg не ну это ок конечно, но с какого это перепуга вы тогда используете `std::string`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch выражение "метод, а не функция" звучит немного странно, не находите?

Comment: даже не знаю что ответить. Может Вы лучше скажете что не так с translateIn10?

Comment: "я в atoi пишу return чтобы потом поместить возвращаемое значение atoi в функцию перевода " - это хорошо, только не надо забывать помещать это значение куда-либо. Сейчас оно никуда не передается

Comment: почему? я в мэйне создал интовую переменную, которую поместил сперва в atoi, где присвоилось значение строки, но уже в виде числа, а потом поместил эту переменную в translateIn10 чтобы она там перевелась в 10ую СС

Comment: @KoVadim да, звучит бредово, не прочитал то как это звучит) Имелось ввиду, что это метод объекта, который юзер и так использует, а не отдельная функция, не имеющая отношения к объекту

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch "метод объекта" звучит ещё круче.  Но это уже придирки.

Answer (score 1):

И в самом деле, зачем просто, если можно сложно?...

```
string s;
cin >> s;
int x = 0;
for(const char * c = s.c_str(); *c; ++c) x = x*7 + (*c - '0');
cout << x;
```

https://ideone.com/tFPZRt

Если даже `c_str()` слишком стандартная :),  то

```
string s;
cin >> s;
int x = 0;
for(const char * c = &s[0]; *c; ++c) x = x*7 + (*c - '0');
cout << x;
```

Comment: боюсь, что string тоже нельзя пользоваться, а `[0]` - так это точно - это же тоже функция. (табличка сарказм опущена)

Comment: @KoVadim ТС **уже** использовал `string` и функции `>>` и `<<`...

Comment: вот это меня и напрягает

Comment: @KoVadim Ну ладно, `printf` и `scanf` можно?...

Comment: я не знаю, это нужно спросить преподавателя автора вопроса.

Comment: imho `getchar()` точно д.б. можно

Comment: думаю, что в большинстве случаев, если преподаватель говорит "нельзя пользоваться стандартными функциями" это либо он не понимает, что он говорит (в том числе и вопрошающий), либо нельзя пользоваться стандартной функцией для данной фичи (то есть, если считаем длину строки, то только strlen/length() нельзя), либо кто то пишет свой компилятор/ос, но тут все очевидно.